# Pass parameters from custom menu to reports

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am attempting to create a menu very similar to the 'Reports' menu on the 'Invoices/Memos' form on the 'Contact' form.

I have successfully added the menu button, and populated it with one item (via 'Automation Steps') so that the menu appears with my menu item and successfully launches my report.

My report has a `ContactID` parameter, as illustrated:

[image: image1]

I have a customization created with the following code:

```
namespace PX.Objects.CR
{
    public class ContactMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ContactMaint>
    {
        public PXAction<Contact> letters;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Letters", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        [PXButton(SpecialType = PXSpecialButtonType.Report)]
        protected virtual IEnumerable Letters(PXAdapter adapter, string reportID)
        {
            PXReportRequiredException ex = null;

            Contact contact = Base.Caches[typeof(Contact)].Current as Contact;

            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();     

            parameters["Contact.ContactID"] = contact.ContactID.ToString();

            ex = PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport(ex, reportID, parameters);

            //this.Save.Press();
            if (ex != null) throw ex;

            return adapter.Get();
        }
    }
}
```

**However, the resulting report does not seem to have the `Contact.ContactID` parameter passed to it.**

I have gotten where I am by loosely interpreting the post [here](http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/08/adding-new-report-button-on-invoices.html).

Could someone help me out? I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a parameter value to a report you need to use the Parameter name. In your example its just "ContactID" so you can set it like this...

```
parameters["ContactID"] = contact.ContactID.ToString();
```

If you need to use non parameter fields by DAC.Field I think you need to add them to Viewer Fields in your report. Then you can use it like you had it (`parameters["MyDac.MyFieldName"] = "somevalue"`).

I had to add viewer fields recently to call a report by non parameter fields. This is the only way I could get that to work. Otherwise the parameters just require the call by parameter name.

Here is an example from Vendor Maintenance calling a vendor report where the report has a parameter named "VendorID":

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters["VendorID"] = vendor.AcctCD;
throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "AP632500", AP.Messages.BalanceByVendor);
```

The example I used recently to call a report not using a parameter (using a viewer field) was the shipment confirmation report. It calls multiple shipments which is why a single parameter will not work. It uses the PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport call to append multiple shipments to a single report call/exception. Sample:

```
//SOShipementEntry.Report(PXAdapter,string)
PXReportRequiredException ex = null;
// Loop on shipments
// ...
parameters["SOShipment.ShipmentNbr"] = order.ShipmentNbr;
// ...
ex = PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport(ex, actualReportID, parameters);
// ...
// End shipments loop
if (ex != null) throw ex;
```

Comment: What you're saying makes sense.  But I am not able to pass even a static string parameter, like `parameters["Number"] = "5"; `  It appears to be coming through blank.  Is there something wrong with how I wrote my method or something?

Comment: If you display that parameter on the report it shows empty? I assume using the report from the sitemap works using the ContactID paramter. Depending on how you are using the parameter maybe it needs to be the CD value vs the ID value passed to the report?

Comment: Well, at this point, I'm just working with the 'Number' parameter till that at least works.  I just tested adding `&Number=5` to the sitemap url, and that works.  But otherwise, it appears blank, yes.

Comment: Ok. I think I got it.  I'm using Automation Steps to populate my menu, and I had made a change to the menu without re-adding the menu item.  Even though it was named the same, I think it had to re-associate it with the menu again, and now it seems to work.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to pass a parameter, like `ContactID`, but then allow for more parameters?  For instance, I would like to launch my report from a Contact, but then allow the user to add additional information that I can't pass from the contact.  Is there a way to first make it stop on the report parameters page?

Comment: no its not possible (using the report screen) that I am aware of. To do this you would have to create a smartpanel on the exiting page to prompt for the input, then pass to your report. You could also create a custom page but a panel is lighter (no page file, sitemap entry, permission, etc.)

Comment: Oh boy, haha.  Do you have any suggestions of resources where I might learn how to do that?

Comment: I would start here. https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(3))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=2fe4a5bb-c249-4d30-b117-af8d1671a589   I see some links on there that can guide you to adding a panel. Its really not that bad. Look on some other pages such as sales order page for examples of its use.

Comment: You can use https://help.acumatica.com and search for PXSmartPanel to find more articles. If you run into any issues just ask another question on the topic here on stackoverflow.